# Is there a way to connect several buttons to several wkwebviews in one VC than "creating a VC for each button and wkwebview"?

Tags: swift

I have 44 UIButtons, each button should segues to a vc with wkwebview with local html.

is there a way to all 44 buttons in one vc?

this is a copy of the sample vc of wkwebview

```
import WebKit
import UIKit
class Acceleration: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var local: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after
        //loading the view.


          let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "acceleration", withExtension: "html")!
          local.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
          local.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

          local.load(request)




    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. There are two things you want to do:

1. Use prepare(for segue:) to specify which url you want to open up in the new VC. (Communicating to new VC which url you want it to open up)
2. Use the url to open up webkview.

Hope this helps!

**Implementation**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    let destVC = segue.destination as! <yourWebkVC>
    destVC.address = <exampleAddress>

}
```

Above means that the VC **yourWebkVC** you are segueing to needs a class variable "address".

Depending on the button you click, **exampleAddress** should be set to whatever url you want that button to open up.

You need to create a variable in **yourWebkVC**

```
class yourWebkVC: UIViewController {

var address = String()
```

You also should create a variable in your viewcontroller where you will be segueing **from**

```
class yourBaseViewController: UIViewController {

var url = String()
```

And then when you click each of the buttons, you change **url** variable to whatever you need it to be.

Comment: Does SFSafariViewControllerDelegate able to use local html files? if yes then how? and thx

Comment: I apologize, I didn't see that you were using html string. SFSafariViewController doesn't allow that. I'll remove that part of the answer, but let me know if the first part makes sense to you.

Comment: it kinda makes sense, but how can I implement it in my case?

Comment: I added more detail, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.Sorry, one more question class address will contain connected buttons?

Comment: Additional detail should help you implement. Best of luck!

Comment: how will url (Bundle.main.url(forResource: "acceleration", withExtension: "html")) change for each button? It is the difficult part I guess, because I have more than one html ,so "acceleration" will change for each button and wkwebview

Comment: For each button, you have to set the url you want the VC to load. So each button would have url = <whatever URL> in its target.